# crear menú HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un menú algo como esto

[image: Menu desktop]

Y lo hice, pero para móvil se descuadra todo soy nuevo en esto y e me dificulta algo porque quiero el slogan siempre visible, fuera del menú y centrado de manera que se vea algo como

[image: menu mobile]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hackeruna.com</a>
      </div>

      <p class="text-center" align="justify" id="slogan" style="font-size: 1em; color: white">un problema, una solución </br> ¡AutoEdifica!</p>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
    <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Si se fijan el slogan siempre se mueve y no se como mantenerlo en la misma linea que los items del menu y el logo de igual manera mantenerlo en medio alineado con el logo y el boton de desplegar los item para vista mobile

Comment: Hmm... Me puedes decir dónde están los menú que muestras en la imagen, en tu código que has ¿publicado? No encuentro nada de lo que muestras en la imagen.

Comment: son unos ejemplos de como mas o menos se veria abajo puse otro intento jeje pero es basicamente lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esto te puede servir, se agrego un navbar-brand con una clase CSS

```css
.nv1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SITIOWEB</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand nv1" href="#">LOGO</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span></span> Opcion 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span></span> Opcion 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
    <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hermano te pasaste, creo que tengo un nuevo amor, muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código, que utilice en un trabajo de mi sitio:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hackeruna.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: es que el problema sigue sienod el mismo el slogan atravesado en el medio , intente con el que me pasaste y funciona pero solo para mobile pero cuando amplias para pantallas grandes el slogan queda al lado del logo y no puedo moverlo :/